# clarity.js by Microsoft slowing overall page loads

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a customer using bing tracking via https://bat.bing.com/bat.js.

On December, 6th 2021 it started calling in clarity.js without the customer making any changes to their code.

This slowed the overall page load by 1 second on mobile and 500ms on desktop. I've been trying to figure out how to disable this JS but I'm not sure what to do as it's being fired from the bing tracking js.

The bing tracking code is being triggered via google tag manager.

Anyone else having this issue and know how to disable clarity.js from being called at all?

[image]

Customer is using Wordpress. Amazing Bing can implement code that slows down a site overall page speed without any notification to the customer.

Comment: The obvious way is to remove the Bing tracker since it triggered this issue. Clarity is integrated into Bing's tracker so removing it by changing that code is likely to be infeasible.

Comment: @Jacob wow, so glad I found this! I was really confused as to why pages were loading noticeably slower on my site... After debugging the network requests, I noticed requests to Clarity. After searching for it, and seeing it was a real-user activity tracker (!), I assumed we'd been hacked through an NPM package or something. I can't believe Bing just randomly started adding this, without warning — you're the only other person I've found online who has seemed to notice so far. Crazy!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems to be added mid-November 2021. Problematic for sure, as it broke our website in certain situations. To disable it, follow these steps:

1. Go to ui.ads.microsoft.com
2. In the top bar go to **Tools**, then under **Conversion tracking** click on **UET tag**
3. In the table at the bottom of the page click on the name of your tag.
4. Under **Enable Microsoft Clarity** disable the checkbox and click the **Save** button.

This should directly remove the script from your website.

Answer (score 4):

I've found the way to turn off Clarity. In Microsoft Advertising, the UET tag has to be re-configured. A checkbox appeared in the UET wizard that allows you to turn off Clarity.

Comment: While this might be correct you expand upon it a little maybe guiding users as to how they get to this checkbox or a screenshot of where the checkbox is?

Comment: It is on ui.ads.microsoft.com -> Tolls menu -> UET tag (Conversion tracking area)
There you'll find the Tag in a list at the bottom of the page. You have to click on the Tag name. At the first screen appears there is an "Enable Microsoft Clarity" with an explanation and a checkbox. This checkbox shall be unticked. 
Don't forget to press the Save button at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

We figured this out by going into our bing web tools and disabling the Clarity integration.

Comment: It would be good to include steps for how to disable the integration to make your answer easier to follow.